# Elevated Account during unit testing when using Claims Based Authentication

Tags: claims-based-auth, unit-testing

I am using SharePoint 2010 and we have switched to using Claims Based Authentication.

When I run unit tests and running code with elevated privileges the web.CurrentUser.LoginName is "MYDOMAIN\Administrator", and an Access Denied-error for the operation that requires the elevated privileges is thrown. (I am logged in  on my computer as "MYDOMAIN\Administrator")

We are expecting "i:0#.w|MYDOMAIN\Administrator", because that is what we get when running from web page.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?